# Expand all sub packages in Enterprise Architect

Tags: c#, package, enterprise-architect

I am working on **Enterprise Architect C#** Add - in. I am creating multiple packages and elements in the project browser.

I am using the `Repository.ShowInProjectView()` API to focus on an element in the project browser. Currently I require all the sub packages of the first package in the model to be expanded once the creation of elements is completed.

Is there an **EA API** available for the same. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Arshad stated.

You can just write a recursive method to call `Repository.ShowInProjectView()` on each of the leaf sub-packages.

It would be like (in a meta-language)

```
func unfold(root) {
  if root.packages.count == 0 { 
    Repository.ShowInProjectView(root.element);
    return;
  }
  for subRoot in root.packages { unfold(subRoot); }
}
```

That will recurse through all sub-packages of a packages. When a leaf is reached it will be unfolded with `Repository.ShowInProjectView` (and all its parents too, of course).

To focus the first element of a package use

```
Repository.ShowInProjectView(package.elements.getat(0))
```

Comment: The subpackage does not expand when you show it in the project browser, so you'll have to use an owned element of the subpackage to force it to expand.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Isn't that just what I'm saying?

Comment: No, I'm saying that you'll have to go down to the element level to expand all packages. If you only iterate the packages, the lowest level of packages won't be expanded.

Comment: @GeertBellekens@ThomasKilian Thank you..if there are multiple packages and if elements are in them..is it possible to focus on the first element available in that package.

Comment: yes, that is possible. But I guess you are somehow having a problem with that? Please explain

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any API calls available for expanding all the sub packages in project browser.

Comment: Thank you. I need to focus on the first element of the first package in the model. Using Repository.ShowInProjectView() focus works correctly on the newly created element but it is not always the first element as stated above.